# My while loop stops after 6 loops despite the fact it is meant to go on forever

Tags: python, while-loop

I am coding a game called tanks in python and there are meant to be 50 rounds however it stops after only 6 can anybody tell me what is going on. It is also meant to stop when the user's score reaches 10 and because there are only 6 rounds there is no way it can be stopped due to that.

Here is my code:

```
#Tanks problem
import random

Grid = [["" for X in range(8)] for Y in range(8)]

PlacePicked=[]

#subroutine to place tanks
def TankPlace():
    global Grid
    for I in range(0,10,1):
        while True:
            X=random.randint(0,7)
            Y=random.randint(0,7)
            if Grid[X][Y]=="T":
                pass
            else:
                Grid[X][Y]="T"
                break

#subroutine to output places already picked
def OutputPlacePicked():
    global PlacePicked
    Places=""
    if len(PlacePicked)==0:
        pass
    else:
        for I in range(0,len(PlacePicked),1):
            Places=Places+PlacePicked[I]+", "
        print("\nSo far you have picked the coordinates of {}".format(Places[:-2]))

#subroutine to check if inputted coordinate is a tank or not
def GameInput(X,Y):
    X1=X-1
    Y1=Y-1
    global Grid
    global PlacePicked
    while True:
        if "({} ,{})".format(X,Y) in PlacePicked:
            print("\nYou have already chosen ({}, {})".format(X, Y))
            X=int(input("\nWhat is your X coordinate?\n"))
            Y=int(input("\nWhat is your Y coordinate?\n"))
        elif Grid[X1][Y1]=="T":
            print("\nTank Hit!")
            PlacePicked.append("({} ,{})".format(X, Y))
            tank="True"
            return tank
        else:
            print("\nTank Missed!")
            PlacePicked.append("({} ,{})".format(X, Y))
            tank="False"
            return tank


#maincode
print("Welcome to Tanks!\n")
print("Instructions:\n-Tanks is a game for 1 player.\n-At the start of the game, the computer places 10 tanks on an 8x8 board but does not\nreveal their locations to the player.\n-Each tank occupies one square on the board.\n-The player enters a grid reference, e.g. (1,5) on each turn.\n-The player destroys the tank if the square is occupied by a tank.\n-The player wins if they destroy all the tanks within 50 turns.")
go=0
score=0
while True:
    TankPlace()
    OutputPlacePicked()
    GameInput(int(input("\nWhat is your X coordinate?\n")), int(input("\nWhat is your Y coordinate?\n")))
    if GameInput=="True":
        score=score+1
    elif GameInput=="False":
        pass
    if score==10:
        print("You Win!")
        break
    else:
        pass
    if go==50:
        print("You Lose")
        break
    else:
        pass
    go=go+1
```

Could anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: There are two explicit and one implicit tests in your *while True* loop. Two of the conditions result in *return*. Your function will therefore terminate. I have no idea what you  think the *break* statements are going to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified you "main" a little:

```
#maincode
print("Welcome to Tanks!\n")
print("""Instructions:
  -Tanks is a game for 1 player.
  -At the start of the game, the computer places 10 tanks on an 8x8 board but does not
   reveal their locations to the player.
  -Each tank occupies one square on the board.
  -The player enters a grid reference, e.g. (1,5) on each turn.
  -The player destroys the tank if the square is occupied by a tank.
  -The player wins if they destroy all the tanks within 50 turns.""")
go=0
score=0
TankPlace()
while True:
    OutputPlacePicked()
    GameInput(int(input("\nWhat is your X coordinate?\n")), int(input("\nWhat is your Y coordinate?\n")))
    if GameInput=="True":
        score=score+1
    elif GameInput=="False":
        pass
    if score==10:
        print("You Win!")
        break
    else:
        pass
    if go==50:
        print("You Lose")
        break
    else:
        pass
    go=go+1
```

Note that I've moved the call to `TankPlace()` before the loop; I figured that placing the tanks anew with each move, wouldn't help the player to win.
I've also removed the `global tank` because it wasn't used.

Anyway, after that I was able to play more than 6 moves.
The game ended prematurely nevertheless, since I guessed a 9 which then produced an exception. It would be a real improvement for the next release to check the user's input.

Comment: Thanks and I will look into your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the compare of GameInput which has been cast to int vs the string "True"

I will let you look it up, but I fear the compare of two different types will degrade to a compare of the bool types and always succeed if the int is non-zero and the string is non-empty..